# Grails: Is there a debug flag I can check?

Tags: grails

I have a few log.debugs() that I don't want to process (since they are heavy) unless the app is currently in debug mode (not production).

Is there a way to check if the grails app is currently in debug mode/development mode?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can test if the current environment is dev (for example) using the following:

```
import grails.util.Environment

if (Environment.current == Environment.DEVELOPMENT ) {
    // Do your dev logging here
}
```

IMO, a better solution than hard-coding the env where this logging happens, is to configure it. For example, to enable debug logging for this class only in the dev environment. add the following to `Config.groovy`

```
log4j = {

  appenders {
    // config for stdout and logfile appenders omitted
  }

  // log everything at error level to stdout and logfile appenders
  root {
    error 'stdout', 'logfile'
  }

  environments {
    development {
      // log this class at debug level in dev env only
      debug 'com.example.MyClass'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the config.groovy the environments are defined.

you can specify what you want the log configuration to be based on the environment the application in running in

```
environments {
    development {
        log4j = {
          // determine what appenders are logging in development...
        }
    }
    production {
        log4j = {
          // determine what appenders are logging in production...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I am aware of this. But I want to know the environment at run time so I can choose to perform certain calculations only if the env is development. Don's answer above looks like what I am looking for.